# CamStudio or Alternative without Malware / Spyware

Tags: screen-sharing, malware

Does CamStudio contain malware? If yes, what is a free open-source alternative to CamStudio that does not have malware or spyware?

Background: I was thinking of installing CamStudio, so I googled it to see if it was safe and I ran across this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamStudio#Malicious_software) that gave me concern. I'm not sure what I am going to download just yet.

Answer (score 2):

A recent download (moments ago) of version 2.7 from the camstudio web site is an executable file. A directed scan by Malwarebytes returns no undesirable software indications. Installation and subsequent scan also returns no trouble.

An alternative, also free, open-source, multi-platform program is [OBS](https://obsproject.com/). This program provides for streaming as well as independent capture, as well as a substantial number of other editing features. No malware has been associated with this software in my research/reading over the last year or so.

Comment: +1 for virus scan AND OBS recommendation.  Tried to find a side-by-side comparison of ~'CamStudio vs OBS...', but found no side-by-side comparisons in google results at this moment (OBS seems less well-known than CamStudio).  Will try to search again either today or tomorrow.